# Auth0 access application specific data in Hooks

Tags: hook, auth0, rules

I'm trying to write something like an email blacklist hook in auth0.
There is a premade rule but since this only checks on login, the user is entered in the database and it only throws an error on login. The description of the **pre-registration hook** is literally what I'm looking for.

The problem is I have multiple applications and I only want this hook to affect one of them. I just don't seem to have any way to identify which application the user tries to sign-up on. I don't seem to have access to the application name or application metadata like I have in rules.

Am I overlooking something or is this really not possible? If not why wouldn't that be possible? It should be something pretty straight forward in my eyes?

Thanks in advance!